# ffmpeg validate command line before running?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there an option to validate the syntax of an ffmpeg command before executing it? 
This would help me build up a command line programmatically and also validate it against ffmpeg right away.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure of if there is an option to validate syntax but the best u can do is use 
`-loglevel`

example : `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -loglevel error output.mmp3`

outputs

`[NULL @ 0x7f9c88831e00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '4.mmp3'
4.mmp3: Invalid argument`

there are 8 `-loglevel`

`quiet` shows nothing.

`panic` Only show fatal errors which could lead the process to crash, such as and assert failure. This is not currently used for anything.

`fatal` Only show fatal errors. These are errors after which the process absolutely cannot continue after.

`error` Show all errors, including ones which can be recovered from.

`warning` Show all warnings and errors. Any message related to possibly incorrect or unexpected events will be shown.

`info` Show informative messages during processing. This is in addition to warnings and errors. This is the default value.

`verbose` Same as info, except more verbose.

`debug` Show everything, including debugging information.

i guess to validate syntax it would be best to use `-loglevel warning` as it shows both warnings and error.

hope this helps.